# Wordpress loads false navigation

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I'm trying to set different navigations in the footer on my wordpress page.

I've registered the different navs inside functions.php:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary'               => __( 'Primary Menu', 'bootstrapcanvaswp' ),
    'language'              => __('Language Menu', 'bootstrapcanvaswp'),
    'rassismus'             => __('Footer Rassismus'),
    'antisemitismus'        => __('Footer Antisemitismus'),
    'rassismusstrafnorm'    => __('Footer Rassismusstrafnorm'),
    'bildung'               => __('Footer Bildung'),
    'medien'                    => __('Footer Medien'),
    'oeffentlichkeit'       => __('Footer Öffentlichkeit'),
    'gra'                   => __('Footer GRA'),
    'meldetool'             => __('Footer Meldetool')));
```

and inside my footer.php I've set the different navigations:

```
<div class="row seven-cols footer-nav">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'rassismus',
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'footer-nav-compl'
             ));
             ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'antisemitismus',
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'footer-nav-compl'
             ));
             ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'rassismusstrafnorm',
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'footer-nav-compl'
             ));
             ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'bildung',
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'footer-nav-compl'
             ));
             ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
         <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'medien',
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'footer-nav-compl'
             ));
             ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
             <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'oeffentlichkeit',
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'footer-nav-compl'
             ));
             ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 last-item">
<?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'gra',
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'footer-nav-compl'
             ));
             ?>
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'meldetool',
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'footer-nav-compl'
             ));
             ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My problem is that some are working well an other not, they just display the nav of "Antisemitismus"

Working:

- Antisemitismus
- Rassismusstrafnorm
- Bildung
- Medien
- Meldetool
- GRA

Not working (displaying Antisemitismus)

- Rassimus (first)
- Oeffentlichkeit (second to last)

In the backend I've set all navigations to the right name and none of the navigations are empty...

Does anyone had a similar problem or knows something to help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `theme_location` instead of `name` - `name` is reffering to the value of the array you send to `register_nav_menus`, not the key.

Comment: Thank you very much... stupid me... should have googled a bit better